# Unable to publish asp.net core web app from visual studio 2015 update 3

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I got this error in visual studio 2015 while publishing  asp.net.core  web app(.net framework)  to azure.

> The "Publish" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.Exception: 
>   Publishing WebApplication1 for .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2/win7-x64
>
> Illegal characters in path.
>   Parameter name: path
>      at Microsoft.DotNet.Tasks.Publish.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuild.

the project builds on local machine and launched the web app successfully but fails to deploy on azure.

Comment: Are you trying to publish it on a path made of something "?" mark. Something like this: http://example.com/publish?q=1

Comment: No It's  just a visual studio web application without any code changes. publish on to azure from visual studio fails.